# How can we delete row from excel using NPOI?

Tags: c#, xlsx, xls, npoi

I am using below code to delete upper rows from .xlsx and I successfully installed NPOI library. It executed successfully but it is unable to delete rows.

```
namespace A
{
    class B
    {
            path = "File path";
            XSSFWorkbook hswb;
            using(FileStream file = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                hswb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            }

            ISheet sheet = hswb.GetSheetAt(0);
            for (int row = 0; row <= sheet.LastRowNum; row++)
            {
                var row1 = sheet.GetRow(row);
                if((row<3) && row1 != null)
                {
                    sheet.RemoveRow(row1);
                    sheet.ShiftRows(row+1,sheet.LastRowNum,-1);
                }
            }
    }
    
}
```

Please help me..
Thanks in Advance!